# How to use the bash shell parameter expansion for filename manipulation

Tags: bash, files, rename, variable

I would like to rename a list of MP3 in the same directory like :

```
001 - toto1.mp3
002 - toto3.mp3
003 - toto5.mp3
004 - toto7.mp3
005 - toto9.mp3
toto10.mp3
toto35.mp3
toto59.mp3
toto75.mp3
```

I tried this example of command :

```
for i in *.mp3 ; do echo "${/[0-9]-/i}" ; done
```

I've got

```
bash: ${/[0-9]-/i}: bad substitution
```

I would like this result :

```
toto1.mp3
toto3.mp3
toto5.mp3
toto7.mp3
toto9.mp3
toto10.mp3
toto35.mp3
toto59.mp3
toto75.mp3
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you read about that substitution operation?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=parameter+substitution

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams In my prompt return

Comment: @n.caillou I didn't know this type of request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set a variable `i` to each filename in the loop, but the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) expects to see the variable name immediate after the `${`; you've instead put it at the end, just before the closing curly brace.

Since you want to remove text only from the front of the filename, use this syntax instead:

```
for i in *.mp3 ; do echo "${i#[0-9][0-9][0-9] - }" ; done
```

which will remove any 3 *leading* digits followed by space dash space.

Comment: I went to find we can put several regex thanks

Comment: `${i#[0-9][0-9]* - }` might be better as it does not require exactly 3 digits. Or `${i#+([0-9]) - }` with extended globs.

Answer (score -3):

Mention all file names in file test.txt

```
$ cat test.txt
001 - toto1.mp3
002 - toto3.mp3
003 - toto5.mp3
004 - toto7.mp3
005 - toto9.mp3
toto10.mp3
toto35.mp3
toto59.mp3
toto75.mp3
```

The following command will search for files which have issues and rename them to the proper name

```
cat test.txt | sed -n '/^0\{2\}/p' | awk '{print "mv" " " $0 " " $3}' |
sed "s/ /&'/1" | sed "s/.mp3/&'/1" | sh
```

```
toto1.mp3
toto3.mp3
toto5.mp3
toto7.mp3
toto9.mp3
```

Comment: This is overly complicated. Creating files is not necessary to do this task. On top of that, please don't use `cat file | cmd` when `sed` accepts files as input. You are creating pointless extra process. The same thing is using pipes from `sed` to another `sed`. You can do that in one sed with the `-e` option.